# How can I do a changing body page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a page with navigation menu on left and body on right. Actually body is consist of sections on  all long.
I would like to display only this section which I click on the left navigation menu. I try to make something like that: 
https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/VirtualBox

Actually I have:

```
<div class="intro-body">
    <div style="padding-top: 120px;" class="container">
        <p class="intro-text">title</p>
        <div id="content" class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
                    <li><a href="#FirstOne"> FirstOne </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#Second"> Second </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#Second2"> Second2 </a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>                  
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <section id="FirstOne">
                    <h2>title title</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p></br>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam est lorem, condimentum sed faucibus ac, aliquam vitae enim.
                    </p>
                </section>
                <section id="Second" style="padding-top: 60px;">
                    <h2>title title</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam est lorem, condimentum sed faucibus ac, aliquam vitae enim. Curabitur sit amet velit nibh. 
                    </p>
                </section>
                <section id="Second2" style="padding-top: 60px;">
                    <h2>title title</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam est lorem, condimentum sed faucibus ac, aliquam vitae enim.
                    </p>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just the same design in all pages. You can use include to do ths or copy the code page to page. sorry on my bad english hope you understand.